# Nodes, Queues, De-queues

Tags: java, queue, nodes, deque

I'm doing this small project of creating a queue and a de-queue in the same class along with using my own Node class and an interface.

The problem i'm facing is I've done all methods but can't get the method removeLast to work because i'm unable to let rear link to the node before it, after getting removed. Please help me with your suggestions? Thank you.

My node class.

```
public class Node<T> {

  T info;
  Node<T> next;

  public Node(T element) {
    info = element;
    next = null;
  }

  public void setInfo(T element) {
    info = element;
  }

  public T getInfo() {
    return info;
  }

  public void setNext(Node<T> next) {
    this.next = next;
  }

  public Node<T> getNext() {
    return next;
  }

}
```

My interface class

```
public interface DequeInterface<T> {

  void addFront(T element);

  void addLast(T element);

  T removeFront();

  T removeLast();

  boolean isEmpty();

  int getSize();
}
```

My deque class

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Deqeue<T> implements DequeInterface {

  public Node<T> front;
  public Node<T> rear;
  int size;

  public Deqeue() {
    front = null;
    rear = null;
    size = 0;
  }

  @Override
  public T removeFront() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    T element = front.getInfo();
    front = front.getNext();
    size--;
    return element;
  }

  @Override
  public T removeLast() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    T element = rear.getInfo();
    size--;
    return element;
  }

  @Override
  public int getSize() {
    return size;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return rear == null;
  }

  @Override
  public void addFront(Object element) {
    Node<T> newNode = front;

    if (newNode == null) {
      rear = front;
    }
      front = new Node(element);
      front.setNext(newNode);
      size++;
  }

  @Override
  public void addLast(Object element) {
    Node<T> newNode = rear;

    if (newNode == null) {
      front = rear;
    }
      rear = new Node(element);
      newNode.setNext(rear);
      size++;

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your list is singly-linked.  Unfortunately, removing the last node of a singly-linked list requires traversing the entire list.  Some alternatives:

- you can make your list doubly-linked
- you can use a random-access array instead of a linked list
- you could use Okasaki's ["purely functional datastructures"](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) deque

Comment: thnx bro, doubly it is but could you help me how to start please

Comment: All the other answers seem to be about this.  But note (as other commenters mention) -- you can't do it without changing the node class.  By definition, a doubly-linked list has nodes with 2 links:  one to the next node in the list, and another to the previous node.

Answer (score 1):

You could have your `Node` have a reference to the previous `Node` as well. This would create a doubly linked list.

```
public class Node<T> {

    T info;
    Node<T> next;
    Node<T> prev;

    public Node(T element) {
        info = element;
        next = null;
        prev = null;
    }


    public void setInfo(T element) {
        info = element;
    }

    public T getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<T> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Node<T> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setPrev(Node<T> prev) {
        this.prev = prev;
    }

    public Node<T> getPrev() {
        return prev;
    }
}
```

Then in the `Deque` class change your `removeFront` and `removeLast` methods to account for `prev`

```
public T removeFront() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
       throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    T element = front.getInfo();
    front = front.getNext();
    front.setPrev(null); //<<<--------------------------
    size--;
    return element;
}

@Override
public T removeLast() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
       throw new NoSuchElementException();
     }
    T element = rear.getInfo();
    rear.getPrev().setNext(null) //<<<--------------
    rear=rear.getPrev(); //<<<--------------

    size--;
    return element;
 }
```

And of course the `addFirst` and `addLast` methods have to be updated as well

```
@Override
public void addFront(Object element) {
    Node<T> newNode = front;

    front = new Node(element);
    front.setNext(newNode);
    if (newNode == null) {
        rear = front;
    }else{
        newNode.setPrev(front);
    }
    size++;
}

@Override
public void addLast(Object element) {
    Node<T> newNode = rear;
    rear = new Node(element);
    newNode.setNext(rear);

    if (newNode == null) {
        front = rear;
    }else{
        newNode.setNext(rear);
    } 
    size++;
}
```

If you would not be allowed to change the code of `Node` and only can change the `removeLast()` method then you could do it like this:

```
@Override
public T removeLast() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
       throw new NoSuchElementException();
     }
    T element = rear.getInfo();
    if(rear==first){
        rear=null;
        first=null;
    }else{
        Node<T> prev = first;
        while(prev.getNext()!=rear){
            prev=prev.getNext();
        }
        rear=prev;
        prev.setNext(null);
   }
    size--;
    return element;
 }
```

But this would be rather inefficient as it requires iterating through the whole list from the beginning.

Comment: thnx bro very much, this is making it double linked set right? my other question could this be done without changing the node class?

Comment: Yes, but that would make the removeLast method very inefficient. You would have to iterate through the whole linked list to get to the last node while remembering the previous node. See edit

Answer (score 0):

Each node should have a pointer to the next node **and** to the previous node.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your list doubly linked (extra management and opportunity for bugs), or you can iterate through the list every time you removeLast and set rear to the new last (much worse performance when removing from last especially on large lists.)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go about doing this is to implement a doubly linked list as opposed to a linked list.  So your node class will need to keep track of the previous element.  You will need to update your add functions to support this.  Once completed, your remove last function will look like this:

```
  @Override
  public T removeLast() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    T element = rear.getInfo();
    size--;
    rear.getPrev().setNext(null);
    rear = rear.getPrev();
    return element;
  }
```

Comment: Would all i need to change in the code is the methods? nothing added in the node class?

Comment: bro, is it possible to make it double without changing the node class?

Comment: @user2272227 No, the whole essence of a doubly linked list is that a node has reference to the node behind it and in front of it.